# Как взять закрытую переменную из другого класса?

Tags: c++

Реализовываю классы TimeSpan(интервал времени) и Time(время). Необходимо перегрузить оператор -, чтобы вышло Time - TimeSpan = Time.

Начал перегружать:

```
Time operator-(const Time &t1, const TimeSpan &t2) {
    Time diffTIme;
    
    diffTIme.days = t1.days - t2.getDays();
    diffTIme.hours = t1.hours - t2.getHours();

}
```

Объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с элементом функцию "lab1::TimeSpan::getDays". Как можно исправить?

```
int TimeSpan::getDays() {
        return days;
    }

int TimeSpan::getHours() {
        return hours;
    }
```

Comment: `getDays` и `getHours` - это константные методы?

Comment: Нет, приложил реализацию в вопрос. Сделать их константными?

Comment: Ну да, ведь у Вас в операторе написано `const TimeSpan &t2`

Comment: Ну и понятно, что если эти функции находятся в `private` или `protected`, то оператор должен быть другом классу `TimeSpan`.

Comment: забыли вернуть diffTIme